# Как выводить дробную часть числа?

Tags: pascal, алгоритм, числа

Как в языке Pascal выводить дробную часть числа?
Например мне надо записать на Pascal следующие числа (в дробной части указать до 4 цифр):

1. 6,38
2. 5!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Format('%.4f', [x]); // дробное число с точностью до 4-го знака
```

Comment: Это Pascal?

Comment: Может и не совсем :)
А что у вас не получается?

Comment: А может `Write(x:10:4);` ?